# Can one automatically get Intellij's regex assistance for one's own regex parameters

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

Intellij provides regex "assistance" (syntax checking) for parameters that expect regular expressions, eg coding:

```
String[] array = string.split("(*.");
```

will mark an error under the regex and provide a tool tip error:

> Unclosed group

This also works for variables, eg

```
String myVar = "(*."; // shows above error here
String[] array = string.split(myVar);
```

But if I create my own method that expects a regex, I don't get this assistance, eg:

```
String[] myMethod(String regexParameter) {
    return someString.split(regexParameter);
}

myMethod("(*."); // no "error" marker like above
```

Although Intellij can figure out `regexParameter` should be a valid regex, it doesn't check it like it does for JDK parameters.

How do I get regex assistance for my own method parameters?

---

#### Note:

Ideally there would be an annotation-based solution or similar, where the method's parameters are "defined" to Intellij as being regex, so all developers automatically get the assistance when they load up the code base.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To activate regex language for a parameter in your IDE, double-click on the regex string and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (shortcut for *Intention Actions*) and choose "Inject Language or Reference", then choose "Regexp" in the resulting list:

[image]

This will permanently attach regex to the parameter at all call sites.

To do this to multiple text fragments, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> keys and keep double-clicking all the instances (the *multi-select* feature in IntelliJ).

To create a parameter that *automatically* has Intellij's language assist feature, so your other dev team members can automatically get regex assistance too, use IntelliJ's [IntelliLang](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/intellilang.html?origin=old_help) plugin by adding jetbrains' annotations library as a compile dependency, eg for gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
}
```

Then to use it, specify `"RegExp"` as the `@Language` for the parameter:

```
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language;

void myMethod(@Language("RegExp") String regex) {
    // some impl
}
```

Regex validation of Strings passed to the method will now work from any method invocation by anyone editing the source code in Intellij.

---

Note: There's an alternative, which is not recommended, to adding a dependency to your build (if you have one), and knowing that the effect is only within your IDE and you'll have to compile within your IDE, Intellij lets you do this:

1. Add `@Language("RegExp")` annotation to the method parameter
2. Click on the red bulb icon to *import annotations into the classpath*

[image]

[image]

Comment: The good news is your suggestion does propagate to all call sites, but it doesn't answer the question. I want to declare the parameter as a regex so *other developers* who use the code will automatically have the language reference, just like we all do for `String.split()`. +1 any how

Comment: Hi Bohemian, I have updated my answer based on your response. (Not sure if the website notifies you of edits). Hope this solution works for you.

Comment: this has lead me to find a better solution IMHO, which I could post as another answer, but I would rather edit it into this answer (you deserve the credit). Would that be OK, or do you want to do it yourself ( I can explain in another comment)?

Comment: You may edit my answer if you have time, I think that would be easier.

Comment: The main change I made was using a proper gradle dependency, so anyone can build the code. Your version would break the build for a team, because the Language annotation would only be on *your* classpath* in *your* IDE. Plus I added some markdown bells and whistles for the keys :)