# PyCharm: regex string intentions for function arguments

Tags: python, regex, pycharm

I have a function that takes a string argument that will be compiled into a regular expression, like so:

```
class Pattern:
    def __init__(self, pattern, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.re = re.compile(pattern)
        self.extras = dict(**kwargs)

    ... more methods ...
```

When I initialize a `Pattern` object, I'd love for PyCharm (actually, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with the Python plugin, but I think that's essentially the same platform) to know that my `pattern` argument string should conform to Python's regular expression syntax, and can be syntax-highlighted, just like when using `re.compile(pattern)`:

```
# This won't be recognized as a regex intention:
p1 = Pattern(r'^(?P<site>[A-Z]{4}).(?P<unit>\d{4})')
# But this will:
p2 = re.compile(r'^(?P<site>[A-Z]{4}).(?P<unit>\d{4})')
```

Is there any way to give the IDE a hint here, that whatever is passed as the `pattern` argument to `Pattern` should have regex syntax?  Ideally in some kind of hint comment or type hint that I could put in the code so it would work for other developers too.

I do know that:

- I could create a plugin for this - in my case that would probably be vast overkill.
- I can do "Inject language or reference" on an ad-hoc basis for any particular call to `Pattern(...)` - but that's temporary, it's tedious when there are a lot of such calls, and it doesn't help other developers read the code more easily.

**Edit:**

This question is the direct analog of "[Can one automatically get Intellij's regex assistance for one's own regex parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009549/can-one-automatically-get-intellijs-regex-assistance-for-ones-own-regex-parame)", but for Python instead of Java.  The [IntelliLang](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1105-intellilang) solution in that answer seems to be only applicable to editing Java or XML files.

Comment: This is *nearly* a duplicate of the above-mentioned question, but I'm doing Python, and AFAICT the solution there only works for Java.  Will update question.

Comment: I guess you're right. It's odd that they would only support it for Java.

Comment: The set of methods that have such behaviour is hardcoded. Please file an issue in the [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY), `Pattern` should be added to them.

Comment: @user2235698 - that's not an option, `Pattern` is a class of my own creation (in my real code I actually renamed it `Rule`).

Comment: Here's the location where the behavior is hardcoded. Just wanted to dash needless hope and work on a workaround that can be done purely in the Python project's codebase.  https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/572ada016f1706da124cebde2cad00473958f942/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/codeInsight/regexp/PythonRegexpInjector.java

Answer (score 4):

I found one way but it works not so smoothly as I expected.

`File - Settings - Editor - Language Injections - Add`:

- `Generic Python`
- ID: `RegExp`
- Places Patterns:

`+ pyLiteralExpression().and(pyMethodArgument("Pattern", 0, "foo.bar.Pattern"))`

Now `RegExp` will be injected into arguments to `Pattern`.

Next step is to share this injection. The injection was created with `IDE`-level scope and it is stored in `IDE` settings that are impossible to share.

To put this injection into project settings you have to move injection to `Project`-level scope (corresponding button is below the button that adds injection) but then it stops working :( The only way is to `Export`-`Import` injection but it is not convenient :(

Feel free to create an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23%7BLanguage%20Injection%7D).

Comment: How would you do it if it was the first argument to a method of the Pattern class rather than the constructor? I've been trying things, and haven't figured it out yet.